# how to make assertequals method indicate all error in list?

Tags: java, junit

I have 2 linked list with size 10
and I want to use `assertEquals(l1,l2);` in a for loop such that it `assertEquals` each node in l1, l2.
If equal show the output or if not equal also show the output so in either case shows the output my purpose is that letting `assertEquals` to indicate all not equal nods or error not to stop in first error

Answer (score 3):

There are two options.

First, use the `ErrorCollector`. This will allow you to accumulate the full list of errors instead of failing on the first one.

[ErrorCollector](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html)

Second, use Hamcrest (built into junit).

```
assertThat(list1, IsIterableContainingInOrder.containsInOrder(list2));
```

I tend to use Hamcrest where ever possible because it provides excellent information on failure.

[IsIterableContainingInOrder](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInOrder.html)